# how we used the xmpp chat between two devices in android

Tags: java, android

I am started my carrier in android and I want to apply the Xmpp chat between the two devices by OpenFire server,but I don't know about this.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [asmack](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack) library from Github, it works very well.

Comment: after use the asmack library ,what should I do??

Comment: how can I use the amack library. please tell me.

Comment: It's really easy to use. You have some tutorial on the web and an example here : http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000119

Comment: how can I use the Host,Port and Service in my project.